# Reroute POST-request to remove /index.php/ [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-post

Is it possible to change the routing of POST requests?

I just found out that i have to include the `/index.php/` in my form action attribute. Bothered me a while that the $_POST array is empty and thought it was a error by CI.

My .htaccess currently looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond $1 !^(phpmyadmin|index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>

<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

Edit:
The form redirects where i want it to go, but the POST data doesn't get there too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

If you're using Apache, please see [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html). If you're using Nginx, please see [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/).

Probably you're using Apache, so your .htaccess should be like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've looked over the docs like 10 times and searched for any possible way on the internet but i can't find a way to reroute this.

Comment: My normal URL requests are working and are rewritten, so that part works perfectly fine, but the POST needs the `/index.php/` with it to get routed correctly and i don't understand why.